# How pass a variable from code behind to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, chart.js

I am trying to pass a value from code behind to JavaScript. I have tried all  ways but when I try to display, it gives undefined.

This is my code behind

```
try
{
   int total = manager.GetAllBooks().Tables[0].Rows.Count;
   lblmsg1.Text = total.ToString();

   filesPercentage.Value = total.ToString();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```
var pct = document.getElementById("<%=filesPercentage.ClientID%>").value;
alert(pct);
```

I will appreciate any help. Am trying to render a chart using chart.js and trying to pass dynamic values instead of static.

Comment: Looks like the correct way, are you getting any error?

Comment: alert(pct);   displays nothing. Actually the charts donot render

Comment: Am passing the value to "sb-admin-charts.js"

Comment: Very less code to understand the issue, any way you can create a working demo?

Comment: The code behind picks the value from the database. This works fine. Now I want to pass this value to the javascript file.That's what is still not working

Comment: What do you mean by creating  a working demo?

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    var showus = $("#filesPercentage").val();
    alert(showus);
});    when i use this, the alert display undefined

Comment: I tried with this code `var pct = document.getElementById("<%=filesPercentage.ClientID%>").value;` it is working fine. It the above comment you are not using the clientid, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182571/discussion-between-raphael-and-kunal-khivensara).

Answer (score 0):

try this
define a property

```
protected string FilesPercentage
{
set {
ViewState["x"]=value;
}
get
{
if(ViewState["x"] != null)
return (string)ViewState["x"];
}
}
```

in your java script:

```
alert('<%=FilesPercentage%>')
```

in your Code Behinde:

```
    try
{
   int total = manager.GetAllBooks().Tables[0].Rows.Count;
   lblmsg1.Text = total.ToString();

   FilesPercentage = total.ToString();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, kindly explain what this does  protected string FilesPercentage
{
set {
ViewState["x"]=value;
}
get
{
if(ViewState["x"] != null)
return (string)ViewState["x"];
}
}

Comment: define this property in your parent Class and use it :)  ,more over  when you want to Pass  a value from CodeBehine To Client(javascript) is best practice  that Define a property in  your code behinde and access it from Client.